# Formatting hanging indents(?) for list of figures, report class, with other detailed formatting for front matter, chapters, etc

Tags: table-of-contents, formatting, report

I am creating a template for use in Report document class with pdfLaTeX compiler in Overleaf. The template specifications are specific for the agency, so there are a lot of specifications.

The minimum reproducible example has the full styling because some packages/commands conflict when used in isolation.

My question is: on the List of Figures, how can I force the indent/alignment for figure captions that spill over onto the next line?

**UPDATE**

I don't want to use `tocloft` because it removes a lot of the other formatting and conflicts with `titletoc` and `titlesec` packages, which must be used.

How can I modify

```
{\let\oldnumberline\numberline %
        \renewcommand{\numberline}{\figurename~\oldnumberline} %
        \listoffigures}
```

to force the alignment/indent on the second line?

[image]

Here is the code, which makes a 7 page PDF. The preamble that formats the insert List of Figures is commented with `% ================ Need help here I think`

```
%-------------------------------------------------------
% Dummy Chapter 1
\begin{filecontents*}[overwrite]{ChapterA.tex}
\chapter{Introduction}
\lipsum[1]
\section{Section Name}
Here is some text, see Figure \ref{fig:a}.
\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width = 0.5\textwidth]{example-image-a}
  \caption[And example figure with a shorter description that still spills over onto the next line. How can I fix the indent?]{An example figure with a long description, many more important words here.} 
  \label{fig:a}
\end{figure}
\subsection{Subsection Name}
Here is a subsection, see \cite{einstein1906new}.
\end{filecontents*}

%-------------------------------------------------------
% Dummy Abstract
\begin{filecontents*}[overwrite]{Abstract.tex}
\cleardoublepage
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Abstract}
\begin{center}
  \fontsize{18pt}{0pt}\selectfont\MakeUppercase{\textbf{abstract}}
\end{center}

\vspace*{24pt}

This is the abstract.
\end{filecontents*}

%-------------------------------------------------------
% Dummy References
\begin{filecontents*}{refs.bib}
@article{einstein1906new,
  title={A new determination of molecular dimensions},
  author={Einstein, Albert},
  journal={Ann. Phys.},
  volume={19},
  pages={289--306},
  year={1906}
}
\end{filecontents*}

%-------------------------------------------------------
% Preamble
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{nameref}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amsmath, amsthm, amssymb, amsfonts}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{appendix}
\usepackage{lipsum}

% set page & paragraph dimensions
\usepackage[letterpaper, margin=1in]{geometry}
\setlength{\parindent}{0.5in}
\setlength{\parskip}{6pt}

% set font
\usepackage[sfdefault]{carlito}

% set-up frontmatter, mainmatter, backmatter
\makeatletter
\newcommand\frontmatter{
    \cleardoublepage
    \pagenumbering{roman}}
\newcommand\mainmatter{
    \cleardoublepage
    \pagenumbering{arabic}}
\newcommand\backmatter{
    \if@openright
        \cleardoublepage
    \else
        \clearpage
    \fi
}
\makeatother

% format headers
\usepackage{titlesec}

\newcommand{\chapterjustification}{}
\newcommand{\chapterfont}{\normalfont}
\newcommand{\chapterfontsize}{\fontsize{22pt}{0pt}\selectfont}

\titleformat{\chapter}%
    {\chapterjustification\chapterfont\chapterfontsize\bfseries\MakeUppercase}%
    {\thechapter}{0.5in}{}
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{80pt}{40pt}

\titleformat{\section}%
    {\normalfont\fontsize{14pt}{0pt}\selectfont\bfseries\MakeUppercase}%
    {\thesection}{0.5in}{}
\titlespacing*{\section}{0pt}{24pt}{12pt}

\titleformat{\subsection}%
    {\normalfont\fontsize{14pt}{0pt}\selectfont\bfseries}%
    {\thesubsection}{0.5in}{}
\titlespacing*{\subsection}{0pt}{18pt}{12pt}

% format table of contents
\usepackage{titletoc}
\contentsmargin{0.2in}

\titlecontents{chapter}[0.5in]{%
    \addvspace{12pt}\bfseries}{%
    \contentslabel{0.5in}\MakeUppercase}{%
    \hspace*{-0.5in}\MakeUppercase}{%
    \titlerule*[0.5pc]{.}\contentspage} % dot density

\titlecontents{section}[1in]{\bfseries}{%
    \contentslabel{0.5in}\MakeUppercase}{%
    \hspace*{-1in}\MakeUppercase}{%
    \titlerule*[0.5pc]{.}\contentspage}
    
\titlecontents{subsection}[1.5in]{\selectfont}{%
    \contentslabel{0.5in}}{%
    \hspace*{-1in}}{%
    \titlerule*[0.5pc]{.}\contentspage}

\newcommand{\insertTOC}{\begingroup
    \cleardoublepage
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Contents}
    \renewcommand{\chapterjustification}{\centering}
    \renewcommand{\chapterfontsize}{\fontsize{16pt}{0pt}\selectfont}
    \titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{0pt}{24pt}
    \tableofcontents
    \endgroup}

% format list of figures & list of tables pages
% ================ Need help here I think (below)
\newcommand{\insertLOF}{\begingroup
    \cleardoublepage
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of Figures}
    \renewcommand{\chapterjustification}{\centering}
    \renewcommand{\chapterfontsize}{\fontsize{16pt}{0pt}\selectfont}
    \titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{0pt}{24pt}
    {\let\oldnumberline\numberline %
        \renewcommand{\numberline}{\figurename~\oldnumberline} %
        \listoffigures}
    \endgroup}
% ================ Need help here I think (above)

\newcommand{\insertLOT}{\begingroup
    \cleardoublepage
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of Tables}
    \renewcommand{\chapterjustification}{\centering}
    \renewcommand{\chapterfontsize}{\fontsize{16pt}{0pt}\selectfont}
    \titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{0pt}{24pt}
    {\let\oldnumberline\numberline %
        \renewcommand{\numberline}{\tablename~\oldnumberline} %
        \listoftables}
    \endgroup}

% load hyperref last to minimize conflicts
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[linktocpage=true]{hyperref}
\hypersetup{colorlinks=true, linkcolor=blue, citecolor=blue}

%-------------------------------------------------------
\begin{document}

\frontmatter
\include{Abstract}
\insertTOC
\insertLOF
\insertLOT

\mainmatter
\include{ChapterA}

\backmatter
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{refs}


\end{document}
%-------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: I assume titlesec can also affect the formatting of `\l@figure`.  Personally, I find it easier to NOT use packages like titlesec.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand your code but I have fiddled around with the `\insertLOF` code, and also used the `tocloft` package to get a better LoF.

```
% format list of figures & list of tables pages
% ================ Need help here I think (below)
\newcommand{\insertLOF}{\begingroup
    \cleardoublepage
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of Figures}
    \renewcommand{\chapterjustification}{\centering}
    \renewcommand{\chapterfontsize}{\fontsize{16pt}{0pt}\selectfont}
    \titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{0pt}{24pt}
    {\let\oldnumberline\numberline %
        \renewcommand{\numberline}{\figurename~\oldnumberline} %
        \listoffigures}
    \endgroup}
% ================ Need help here I think (above)

% and here it is --- Peter W.
\usepackage{tocloft}
\renewcommand{\cftloftitlefont}{\hfill\Large}
\renewcommand{\cftafterloftitle}{\hfill}

\renewcommand{\insertLOF}{%
  \cleardoublepage
  \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of Figures}
  \listoffigures
}
```

You should do something similar for `\insertLOT`.

I feel that the code you show is unnecessarily complicated (detailed), but then I'm a GOM (Grumpy Old Man).
Why not try the `memoir` class (a superset of `book` and `report`) which, for example, can automatically add the LoF and LoT titles to the ToC?